# Why does current_url raise "No JSON object could be decoded" w/ Selenium & PhantomJS on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ubuntu, phantomjs

Here's the repro:

```
sudo apt install phantomjs
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
python
>>> import selenium.webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
>>> browser = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
>>> browser.get('http://example.com')
>>> browser.title
u'Example Domain'
>>> browser.current_url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 454, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib.python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
    value = json.loads(value_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Notes:

- I'm running in a VM with all updates installed (`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` have been run).
- This problem appears to also be captured as [Ubuntu bug 1569899](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-selenium/+bug/1569899). I have yet to try the fix suggested (build PhantomJS from tarball).
- The `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` variable is to fix the error: "*QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display*" (Debian bug [817277](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=817277), PhantomJS issue [14376](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14376))

**UPDATE** I added a simple `print` to capture the raw response and here's what it was:

```
{'status': 404, 'value': u"Error: - Unable to load Atom 'execute_script' from file ':/ghostdriver/./third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_script.js'"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears the `phantomjs` package is simply broken (missing components). There are solutions using `npm` out there but since I'm doing Python I wanted to avoid that. Here's what I ended up doing to fix this:

```
unset QT_QPA_PLATFORM
sudo apt purge phantomjs
wget -q https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar xvjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/
```

My other binaries are in `/usr/local/bin` but it would work also if you put them in `/usr/bin`.